# How to sync indexes between two elastic search clusters residing on two different servers?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am pretty new to elastic search. I have two elastic search running on two different servers,

xx.xx.xx.xx:9200
cluster-name : ABC
Node-name : XYZ

and

zz.zz.zz.zz:9200
cluster-name : ABC
Node-name : XYZ

I have same indexes on both servers. I want to have a setup that if indexes of one server's cluster get change then the second should be having the same changes(syncing both the clusters). is it possible? if yes, then please help me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have got the solution. As I installed through rpm packages, in the logs I was getting below error:

[2017-08-24T03:50:01,331][INFO ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery ] [node-2] failed to send join request to master [{node-1}{sYqhGZc4QyK_cbZ9_cz8gQ}{BBHUedE6Roaw0AMiYnQwIg}{172.31.4.119}{172.31.4.119:9300}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[node-1][172.31.4.119:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[can’t add node {node-2}{sYqhGZc4QyK_cbZ9_cz8gQ}{FbDpyWy2S7SS1c8TvLsnfQ}{172.31.4.118}{172.31.4.118:9300}, found existing node {node-1}{sYqhGZc4QyK_cbZ9_cz8gQ}{BBHUedE6Roaw0AMiYnQwIg}{172.31.4.119}{172.31.4.119:9300} with the same id but is a different node instance]; ]

I had deleted contents of data folder(/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0) and restarted both the servers and it worked for me.